# Null Pointer Access Warning

Tags: java, servlets

A part of the code I made should have looked like this.

```
String name = request.getParameter("Name");
if(name!=null && !name.isEmpty())
{
    DO SOMETHING
}
```

But ended up using '||' operator rather than '&&' operator. And i was given a *warning* at

> ***name***.isEmpty()

saying

> Null Pointer Access: The variable name can only be null at this location.

Can somebody explain me why that happened?

And by the way, '**request**' is a HttpServletRequest Object that i get from a previous class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
if(name!=null || !name.isEmpty())
```

Then if the second part is reached, `name` is `null` due to [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Remember that `false && anything` is `false` and `true || anything` is `true`.

Answer (score 4):

```
name != null || !name.isEmpty()
```

1. If name is not null, the second condition is never checked;
2. if name is null, the second condition is checked and throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String name = request.getParameter("Name") != null ? request.getParameter("Name") : "";
```

to ensure that `name` is not `null`. And then

```
if (name.isEmpty()) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(name!=null ){
   if(!name.isEmpty()){
       //body
   }
}
```

Comment: `name.equals(null)` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `name` is `null`.